# ASP Web Forms Scaffolding

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, webforms, scaffolding

I am testing out the new Scaffolding ability in vs2013 for WebForms. I have my model class but for some reason its not generating the fields of related data. Here's my class:

```
public class StaffAvaliability
{
    [Key]
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int StaffAvaliabilityId { get; set; }

    public int StaffMemberId { get; set; }

    [EnumDataType(typeof(Award)), Display(Name = "Award Rate")]
    public virtual Award AwardId { get; set; }

    [EnumDataType(typeof(DaysOfTheWeek)), Display(Name = "Day")]
    public DaysOfTheWeek Day { get; set; }

    public DateTime ShiftStart { get; set; }

    public DateTime ShiftEnd { get; set; }

    public string StaffAvaliabilityNotes { get; set; }
}

public enum DaysOfTheWeek
{
    Monday,
    Tuesday,
    Wednesday,
    Thursday,
    Friday,
    Saturday,
    Sunday
}
```

Here I am wanting to get the award id's from the Award table and have them generated in a  drop down.

Any help is much appreciated, this is my first go at using scaffolding and I've gotta say it sounds like a massive timesaver!

Comment: Did you find out how to do this?

Comment: sure did mate, I will post an answer later today.